# PHP Mysql Query HELP PLEASE

Tags: mysql

I have something like this in a mysql row value:

```
{15;16;}
```

And I want a mysql_query to update it. It must be something like it **"{15;16;17}"** So I need to delete last "}" add my text and close with "}"

to delete last "}" code:

```
SUBSTRING(server_players, 1, LENGTH(server_players)-1)
```

to add text this :

```
CONCAT(server_players, '17;}')
```

but I don't know how to build a one query :(

It's the query :

```
UPDATE members SET "Here must be built code" WHERE server_id=1
```

Comment: Set the column to `server_players`, if you are getting correct string in it after `CONCAT`.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Generally this sort of manipulation is best done in the application, but additionally, it's not a great idea to store data in that format. Relational databases prefer things to be broken out as individual records.

That said, your solution is to nest the two things:

```
UPDATE members
  SET server_players=CONCAT(SUBSTRING(server_players, 1, LENGTH(server_players)-1), '17;}')
  WHERE server_id=1
```

The query code for removing an arbitrary player from your list will be even more complicated. I **strongly** suggest not using this schema.

As you can see this is a very, very messy way to do what should be done as:

```
INSERT INTO server_players (server_id, player_id) VALUES (1, 17)
```

Where you have a table specifically for the players on a server.

Remember proper relational tables have the advantage of being quick to query because they're indexed, and you can do useful things with that data like apply a `JOIN` to pre-load other information.